# Every time that my WD external drive spins-down, Unsafe_shutdown_count (SMART) increases

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

I've got a brand new [WD D10](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/external-drives/wd-black-d10-game-drive-usb-3-2-hdd) for about 20 days now, and I'm using it with my Linux machine.

To turn it off, I first `umount` the drive, then I use `udisksctl power-off /dev/xxx` to safely remove the device. This is what I'm doing for all my drives for years and I have never had any problems.

Here is a refined output of `smartctl` for my `WD Elements` after two years of usage:

```
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       994
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1145
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       66
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   195   195   000    Old_age   Always       -       17638
```

And here is my `WD D10` after 20 days:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   131   131   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       98
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   158   158   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       512 (Average 513)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       99
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   128   128   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       18
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       98
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       90
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       122
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       122
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 25/63)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

As the output of `smartctl` does not contain the value of `Unsafe_shutdown_count` here is a screenshot from **HDTune**:

[image]

What I noticed was that the value of `Power-Off_Retract_Count` and `Unsafe_shutdown_count` are larger than `Start_Stop_Count`. That was when I paid a little bit more attention to the numbers and how the are being increased to find out that each time that the drive *spins down* `Power-Off_Retract_Count` and `Unsafe_shutdown_count` are being increased by one.

Now I'm concerned about the health of my drive. It's a Desktop drive and I want to use it as an expanding storage, each spin down being counted as an `Unsafe_Shutdown_Count` is kinda scary as the drive might spin down more than of 100 times a day.

Is there any reason why spinning down is being counted as `Unsafe_Shutdown_Count`? Is there any way to prevent it?

<sub>Because of where I live it's really hard for me to reach Western Digital.</sub>

Comment: On one of my WD drives this values basically just increases every hour the dive is spinning. It’s marked as _old_age_, too, so maybe just ignore it.

Comment: @DanielB As `Unsafe_shutdown_count` is also being increased with each spin down I'm a little bit concern about what is happening.

Comment: As far as I know 0xc1 / 193 refers to the count the drive has parked its heads, and that happening too frequently can be a concern. I'm not sure if that always happens when the drive enters standby mode, but standby mode can be triggered by a few things, such as APM level or the USB-SATA bridge (some firmware has its own timeout for sending STANDBY command). There's also the WD-specific "idle3" (not sure if it's still "popular" though).

Comment: @TomYan `C1` being increased after each spin-down is acceptable, what I'm really concern here is `Unsafe_Shutdown_Count` (`C0`) and why it has the same value of `C1`.

Comment: Those names / descriptions don't always make a lot of sense. (SMART is not exactly standardized.) What the items really refers to is to some extent only known by the vendor and could even differ among models. Unfortunately not very often there would be documention released from the vendor that clearly annotate those items. Most of the time the names are guesses based on past experience or so and could differ among programs (and versions of each of them).

Answer (score 1):

The `Power-Off_Retract_Count` is not something to be concerned about. If you power down your drive the heads are loaded off the media, that's normal. See [here](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9127).

The values to be concerned about are the following values, which are all 0 (raw value) in your case, so you should be all good:

- Reallocated Sectors Count
- Spin Retry Count
- Reallocation Event Count
- Current Pending Sector Count
- Offline_Uncorrectable
- ... (etc.)

Eventually, all drives will fail, make sure that your drive doesn't spin up/down unnecessarily (this can actually decrease life span depending on the frequency) but if it does it for the unmounting that is fine.

Why it's counted as `Unsafe_Shutdown_Count` (where did you get the information that it's the same as Power-Off_Retract_Count?) it's a little baffling, but since you dismount the drive prior to shutting down, I wouldn't be concerned much, seems not to be [an uncommon issue](https://community.wd.com/t/unsafe-shutdown-count-increase-by-1-every-time-when-shutdown-laptop-normally/16028) and [here](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/88016-unsafe-shutdown-count-goes-higher-everytime-i-shutdown-pc-normally.html) as well, etc.

To be on the safe side write an email to WD support (but at the moment I wouldn't be too concerned). **However - ALWAYS keep a backup!!**

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've updated my question with a picture, that might clarify why  I think `Unsafe_Shutdown_Count` and  `Power-Off_Retract_Count` are the same.

Comment: It's the same SMART ID (192 or C0 in hex), it can mean [both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) but the actual meaning is defined by the manufacturer, I would check with WD. To me it seem that its Power-Off_Retract_Count.

Comment: @FooBar any updates on the issue?

Comment: Nothing new yet.